# Thread execution order

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have [the following C# code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.thread.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

// Simple threading scenario:  Start a static method running
// on a second thread.
public class ThreadExample {
    // The ThreadProc method is called when the thread starts.
    // It loops ten times, writing to the console and yielding 
    // the rest of its time slice each time, and then ends.
    public static void ThreadProc() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
            // Yield the rest of the time slice.
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Start a second thread.");
        // The constructor for the Thread class requires a ThreadStart 
        // delegate that represents the method to be executed on the 
        // thread.  C# simplifies the creation of this delegate.
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

        // Start ThreadProc.  Note that on a uniprocessor, the new 
        // thread does not get any processor time until the main thread 
        // is preempted or yields.  Uncomment the Thread.Sleep that 
        // follows t.Start() to see the difference.
        t.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Call Join(), to wait until ThreadProc ends.");
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread: ThreadProc.Join has returned.  Press Enter to end program.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It's a long time since I studied the thread to university, the only thing that I still remember is:

> thread execution is pretty unpredictable and may vary based underlayng
>   OS.

So the real question is: why I can't be sure not even about the **first** execution of ThreadProc? What happen when I execute `t.Start()`? Why `ThreadProc: 0` isn't printed immediately after `Main thread: Start a second thread` in every execution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why I can't be sure not even about the first execution of ThreadProc?

Because this is nondeterministic neither by .NET nor `Windows` OS documentation (I suppose you are using Windows)

> What happen when I execute t.Start()?

Thread will be scheduled by OS for execution. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx): "Causes a thread to be scheduled for execution."

> Why ThreadProc: 0 isn't printed immediately after Main thread: Start a
>   second thread in every execution?

Because there is some delay between `Thread.Start()` call and actual thread start