# If i start 2 threads one immediately after another, why is there no guarantee that the first thread will start first?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

If I start two threads, one immediately after another, why is there no guarantee that the first thread will be started first?

Comment: Threads are in control of your os, not in the control of the program.

Comment: This isn't about when a thread gets started, it is about when the code of the thread runs.  Which is entirely nondeterministic, including its first statement.  The OS thread scheduler makes the choice, it cares very little about how "old" a thread might be.  Only when the thread didn't get elected to run for an extended time might it bump up its priority.

Comment: Why _should_ there be a guarantee? The whole point of threads is that they run independently of one another (i.e., they run _concurrently_) except at the occasional places where you need them to synchronize with each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064286/thread-execution-order)

Comment: Fix punctuation.